# Easier way to hide/show divs with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide all the ones with the class `.Hide` and then show a specific div according to which link I clicked.
I got this so far, but is there a easier way?

My code so far: (using JQuery)

```
$(".btn").click(function (){
        $(".Hide").hide("fast");
    });

    $("#btn_one").click(function () {
        $("#one").show("fast");
    });

    $("#btn_two").click(function () {
        $("#two").show("fast");
    });

    $("#btn_three").click(function () {
        $("#three").show("fast");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="btn_one" class="btn">one</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_two" class="btn">one</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_three" class="btn">one</a>

<div id="one" class="Hide">1</div>
<div id="two" class="Hide">2</div>
<div id="three" class="Hide">3</div>
```

Comment: Quick simple way to do it using data attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/EdR5A/

Comment: See this instead, i updated it with comments and clarified it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/EdR5A/1/ It's by far the most clean solution imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data attributes could be an option:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".Hide").hide("fast");
    $("#" + $(this).data('type')).show("fast"); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="btn_one" data-type="one" class="btn">one</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_two" data-type="two" class="btn">one</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_three" data-type="three" class="btn">one</a>
```

You can use `data-something` to refer corresponding element.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/u8CAD/

Answer (score 2):

As it is right now, I think that's about as good as you can make it (you could place the hiding code in a function and reference from all, but it's about the same).

If you can change the HTML code a bit, and add a `rel` attribute to the buttons, containing the id of the related element, then you can really make the code better (I'm using `.click()` but if your jQuery version allows you should change to `.on()`):

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.Hide').hide("fast");
  $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).show("fast");
}
```

And the relevant HTML

```
<a href="#" id="btn_one" class="btn" rel="one">one</a>
<div id="one" class="Hide">1</div>
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution indeed :) if I can give you ten upvotes, I totally would.

Comment: also checkout @dfsq , beat me to it for a few seconds to it, and has a compatible alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
$("a.btn[id^=btn]").click(function() {
    $(".Hide").hide("fast");
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(4);
    $("#" + id).show("fast");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dNjG7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your links and divs are in a separate container, you can use this:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="btn">one</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">two</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">three</a>
</nav>

<div>
    <div class="Hide">1</div>
    <div class="Hide">2</div>
    <div class="Hide">3</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
     $(".Hide").hide("fast").eq( $(this).index() ).show("fast");
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/TUrgG/

This one doesn't need any ids nor `data-*`-attributes.

Comment: Who said that they would? It's not stated in the question.

Comment: Who ever downvoted this answer should really consider to review it's vote. +1 From me

Comment: @insertusernamehere But why not aim to make it as flexible as possible? He might not have stated it in the question but that's no reason to not make the code as good as possible. What if he needs the same functionality in another container somewhere? This is simply not the best way to go about it. I posted a suggestion as a comment to the OP, see the code for a smarter approach.

Comment: I'm a friend of "*keep it simple*". If there's no need to be as flexible as possible, don't be. Your code works fine too, but is definitely more complex than this one and you need to introduce more attributes. But in the end, it think it doesn't even matter, as both do the same.

Answer (score -4):

Firstly, you can hide all of them with the following:

```
$(".Hide").hide();
```

After that you need to parse the ID of the clicked link to get the ID or the DIV that needs to be shown. For that you could do:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("btn_", "");
```

This solution would be based on your current HTML structure, with no changes.

---

However, I would recommend that you use a `data-*` attribute to store the ID. A complete solution would look like this:

```
<a href="#" id="btn_one" data-showid="one" class="btn">one</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_two" data-showid="two" class="btn">two</a>
<a href="#" id="btn_three" data-showid="three" class="btn">three</a>

<div id="one" class="Hide">1</div>
<div id="two" class="Hide">2</div>
<div id="three" class="Hide">3</div>
```

with the following javascript/JQuery:

```
$(".btn").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".Hide").hide();
   var id = $(this).data("showid");
   $("#" + id).show();
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/V9JQT/)

Comment: Whats with all the downvotes??? My answer is basically the same as the accepted one. Except mine goes the extra effort of also suggesting how it could be done without changing the current HTML